# Can I get ALL contact's emails in CiviCRM reports?

Tags: civireport, searchkit

By default, CiviCRM Reports include only contact's **Primary email**.

How can I create a report which includes **all contact's emails**?

**Alternatively**, is there a way I can export ALL users with ALL emails? (There is with Search Kit, but an option with Reports would be much better for automatic processing.)

Answer (score 3):

It's simple with Search Kit: see [here](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/search#/create/Contact?params=%7B%22version%22:4,%22select%22:%5B%22id%22,%22display_name%22,%22GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT%20Contact_Email_contact_id_01.email)%20AS%20GROUP_CONCAT_Contact_Email_contact_id_01_email%22%5D,%22orderBy%22:%7B%7D,%22where%22:%5B%5D,%22groupBy%22:%5B%22id%22%5D,%22join%22:%5B%5B%22Email%20AS%20Contact_Email_contact_id_01%22,%22LEFT%22,%5B%22id%22,%22%3D%22,%22Contact_Email_contact_id_01.contact_id%22%5D%5D%5D,%22having%22:%5B%5D%7D)

[image]

You say: "There is with Search Kit, but an option with Reports would be much better for automatic processing" - what 'automatic processing' are you referring to?  Search Kit surpasses Reports in many ways and will eventually replace them so far as I know so it's useful to understand what people are doing with reports that can't be done, or is harder, with Search Kit.

Comment: Perhaps @Aivars is referring to the feature that allows reports to be emailed out on a regular basis.

Comment: @NoahMiller that's absolutely right, we are emailing reports automatically. From there, the data is automatically inserted and regularly updated in Google Spreadsheets, making it available for further processing.

Comment: I've noted that here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3478

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SQL Tasks](https://civicrm.org/extensions/sql-tasks-extension-configurable-recurring-tasks) to generate the report you're looking for, which can automatically deliver a CSV to you via email.  Depending on the format you're looking for, you'll want something like:

```
SELECT display_name, email 
FROM civicrm_contact cc 
JOIN civicrm_email ce ON cc.id = ce.contact_id;
```

OR

```
SELECT display_name, GROUP_CONCAT(email)
FROM civicrm_contact cc 
JOIN civicrm_email ce ON cc.id = ce.contact_id
GROUP BY display_name;
```

Comment: Interesting. I will check it out.